# Excel Macro displays error after executing sql query

Tags: excel, vba

Below is the code for my macro. The issue is my macro runs fine(executes query and puts data on the spreadsheet) but I get this error

> RunTime Error '13' Type Mismatch

The macro executes the query and puts the data on the spreadsheet but I get the error with yellow highlight on this line

> `Strcode = Target.Value`

Any suggestions?

```
    Sub JobTaskHistory(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim sqlstring As String
Dim connstring As String
Dim Strcode As String

'Strcode = Trim(InputBox("Please enter a Job Number", "Job Task history"))
Strcode = Target.Cells(1, 1).Value
sqlstring = "select distinct m.JobNumber , cast(m.ExpectedDate as DATE) 'Ship Date'  &_
            " from ArchiveJobHeader m  left join AuxiliaryInfoFile af (nolock) on af.jobnumber=m.jobnumber left join CostEntry ce (NOLOCK) on ce.sJobNumber = m.JobNumber  left join CostCenterFile cc (nolock) ON cc.Code = ce.sDepartmentCode  left join JobExtra j on j.JobNumber = m.JobNumber   & _
             " where m.JobNumber = '" & Trim(Strcode) & "'" & _
             " order by 'Resulttime'"
connstring = "ODBC;DSN=Test;UID=Test;PWD=Test123"

 Dim thisQT As QueryTable
 Dim lastRow As Long, nextRow As Long

 lastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
 nextRow = lastRow + 1

 'Set thisQT = ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=connstring, Destination:=Range("a1", "a1000"))
Set thisQT = ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add( _
                 Connection:=connstring, _
                 Destination:=Range("A" & nextRow))
 thisQT.BackgroundQuery = False

 thisQT.Sql = sqlstring


thisQT.Refresh

End Sub


Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Call JobTaskHistory(Target.Cells(1, 1).Value)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get this error if your `Range` (`Target`) contains more than one cell.

For example:

```
Dim rangeTest As Range

Set rangeTest = Range("A1")
MsgBox rangeTest.Value ' This works.

Set rangeTest = Range("A1:B1")
MsgBox rangeTest.Value ' This fails with runtime 13 error.
```

So to fix it, make sure you are only referencing a single cell. To be safe, you can just access the first cell in the range using this:

```
' This will work if Target is a single cell or multiple.
' It will always use the upper-left most cell in the range.
Strcode = Target.Cells(1, 1).Value
```

---

**Update after you made your edit**

This will cause an error:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Call JobTaskHistory(Target.Cells(1, 1).Value)
End Sub
```

Because you are passing in a *value* and not a `Range` which your function expects. Replace the line with this to make it compatible with your `JobTaskHistory` method:

```
Call JobTaskHistory(Target)
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I tried using the the example you suggested but still get the same error. Can you help me fix this? Stuck with this issue for long time. Thanks again.

Comment: @Node.JSBeginner - What are the cells included in the `Target` range when you call this function?

Comment: @Node.JSBeginner - Please see the question in my previous comment. I can reproduce your exact error when `Target` is a range containing more than 1 cell. The fixed noted above worked for me.

Comment: When I run the macro (after editing per your answer), my sql query runs in loop for 104 times and puts column headers on the spreadsheet. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: @Node.JSBeginner - It sounds like the subject of this question has been resolved, so that would be a different issue. I would suggest creating another question with the appropriate context defined for it.